# Configuration Management Module Keeps Saying 'needs attention'

Tags: 7, configuration

I've just started using the [configuration module](http://drupal.org/project/configuration) to keep my Drupal database in sync between my development and live environments.

Documentation for this module is sparse, and I'm trying to understand how it works.

I went to the UI and started tracking a single custom content type. It goes ahead an tells me it is tracking that content type, plus all its custom fields and everything which is great.

But then when I go to the 'tracking' tab, it lists all the stuff it is tracking, and in the side tabs, it says that things 'need attention', for example the 'content type' tab says '1 needs attention'. Yet, when I look at the status of the tracked configurations, it simply says 'In sync'.

What exactly 'needs attention', and how do I make it stop saying this?

Comment: which version do you use?

Comment: I'm using 7.x-2.x-dev

Answer (score 0):

It means that there is a difference between activestore and datastore for those items.

[image: See on the left side]

Below you see that those items are overriden. The ones in data store are old versions. If this is a dev environment and those changes are necessarry, you can write these changes to datastore and push/migrate to prod environment.

The below changes are for example purpose and they are not necessarry to put to prod version, since they are about things like last running of cron, etc.

[image: See overriden]

The below image a real change in activestore. You can write that down on datastore by clicking Write Activestore to Datastore.

[image]